# How to determine which type of sql query is entered by user in java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I was working on simple project which takes sql query from user and displays the results in JTable 
I want to determine if select statement was entered or any other DML/DDL statement was entered so I can call `executeQuery()` or `executeUpdate()` accordingly. 
I thought of checking the query if it begins with select. Is there a better way to do this.
[image]

Comment: I suggest you use 2 text areas for entering SQL Command. one for DDL commands and other for DML commands.

Comment: @ka4tik I don't think apart from matching `Select`, `create` etc in query String you can find out post firing query into DB, you can have two types, say `DDLType` and `DMLType`, based on selection, another dropdown can have subtypes like `DDL -> Create, Drop etc`, let user choose an option in dropdown, then build a query builder

Comment: As mentioned by @Blip. I would suggest you to use a single `JTextField` , from where you get the text and match it DDL/DMK statements and then call the query respectively

Comment: Just use execute(): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: You could use Regex to compare the input if you have any knowledge of it 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-Minute-Regex-Tutorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of trying to decide if you need to call `executeQuery` or `executeUpdate`, you can just use `execute` instead.

The javadoc of [`Statement.execute(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute-java.lang.String-) says:

> Executes the given SQL statement, which may return multiple results. In some (uncommon) situations, a single SQL statement may return multiple result sets and/or update counts. Normally you can ignore this unless you are (1) executing a stored procedure that you know may return multiple results or **(2) you are dynamically executing an unknown SQL string.**

(emphasis mine)

The `execute` methods have a boolean return value which means:

- `false`: first result is either an update count, or there are no results
- `true` : first result is a result set

I am intentionally saying **first** result, as JDBC allows for a single statement having multiple results (eg a SQL Server stored procedure can return multiple result sets and update counts in any order).

If `false`, you need to call [`getUpdateCount`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getUpdateCount--). This either returns an update count (0 or higher), or `-1` to indicate there are no more results. As an aside: calling `getUpdateCount` when the result was `true` should also return `-1`.

If `true`, you need to call [`getResultSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getResultSet--) to obtain the result set.

To process more results (that is if you either just processed a result set or `getUpdateCount` was not `-1`), then you call [`getMoreResults`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getMoreResults--), which also returns a boolean, with the exact same meaning as above, etc.

This sounds complex, but most databases only support a single result set, and if you only care about a result set, then you only need to check if `execute` returned `true` to then use `getResultset` (or not if `false`).